# What issue am I having running the same macro twice in the same workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook for which I need to use goal seek to calculate a value I've named "Zeta". I got the code working on one sheet, but when I try to use the same code on another sheet, it doesn't work. I don't get it

The code that works is shown below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim inputCells As Range
'List all input cells
Set inputCells = Range("Zeta, BiotTarget,Diameter,k,h, " & _
    "BiotTarget, SetCell, ChangeCell")

If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), inputCells) Is Nothing Then
    'Run the Goalseek Macro
    Range(Range("SetCell").Value).GoalSeek Goal:=Range(Range("ToCell").Value), ChangingCell:=Range(Range("ChangeCell").Value)
End If
End Sub
```

The code that does not work is copy pasted from the above code with slight alterations to get it to work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim inputCells As Range
'List all input cells
Set inputCells1 = Range("Zeta1, BiotTarget1,Thickness,kone,hone, " & _
    "BiotTarget1, SetCell1, ChangeCell1")

If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), inputCells1) Is Nothing Then
    'Run the Goalseek Macro
    Range(Range("SetCell1").Value).GoalSeek Goal:=Range(Range("ToCell1").Value), ChangingCell:=Range(Range("ChangeCell1").Value)
End If
End Sub
```

When I try to run the Macro, it gives error shown in the photo. All the cells are the same idea, but I renamed them with a 1 at the end to show the difference. Also, Diameter is changed to thickness.

Can anyone help out here?

[image]

Comment: This suggests that the worksheet containing this code has no named range corresponding to one of the names in your snippet.

Comment: Side note, change `Range(Target.Address)` to just `Target`.